# Ubuntu 12.04 php, mysql-server and phpmyadmin installation error with apache2 web-server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-12.04

I have installed apache2 web-server and I want to install php, mysql and phpmyadmin in ubuntu 12.04

I followed this **[link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu)**

but I got this error

```
start: Job failed to start invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action
"start" failed. No apport report written because the error message
indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                           dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):  subprocess installed post-installation script returned
 error exit status 1 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of
 mysql-server:  mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:  
 Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet. dpkg: error processing
 mysql-server (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving
 unconfigured Errors were encountered while processing: 
 mysql-server-5.5  mysql-server
```

I tried again and again but I didn't get any solution 
please help me

Answer (score 0):

I have seen these kind of errors when other things have been installed but the machine not rebooted. I suggest you try:

1) reboot
2) sudo apt-get update
3) sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
4) sudo apt-get install phpadmin

you are using 12.04. The third step may not work - I forget when they brought in the caret syntax. If it doesn't work install tasksel and use that to install the lamp server.

HTH

Paul